# how to import certificate from the server and generate jks for it?

Tags: java, ssl, https, jks

Some outer service which I use change http to https, and now I can't receive responses to my requests from it. So, I want to configure SSLSettings for my http requests. And as I understand I should "convert" public certificate from outer service (site) to jks file, to use in SSLSettings.
When I request to outer service, I receive an exception:

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not
>   authenticated

I'm novice in ssl.
With command:

```
openssl s_client -connect some.host:443 | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout
```

I receive the answer:

```
depth=3 C = US, O = "The Go Daddy Group, Inc.", OU = Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
verify return:0

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

//.....

-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I don't really understand, in what format I receive this public key and
what should I do next to create jks file?
And I don't really understand, Am I in the right direction?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Do you have to import a server certificate, or create and sign a client certificate?

Comment: Some outer service which I use change http to https, and now I can't receive responses to my requests from it.
So, I want to configure SSLSettings for my http requests. And as I understand I should "convert" public certificate from outer service (site) to jks file, to use in SSLSettings.

Comment: So you have to import a server certificate. Would it be possible for you to have answered the question directly?

Answer (score 0):

With keytool you can generate your keystore (.jks file ). you should use a command like :

```
keytool -keystore clientkeystore -genkey -alias client
```

for more detailed instructions check this url:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i am getting your question right but to generate a keystore you can use the below comand

`keytool -genkeypair -keysize 2048 -keyalg RSA -alias  testalias -keystore /test.keystore -ext SAN=dns:localhost,ip:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

and later extract the public key from it